# What's the meaning of the expression "financial savy" in the phrase bellow?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Record companies expect to make a profit, and little concern themselves with a given performer's lack of business or financial savvy, as artists such as George Michael have discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Financial savvy" is one's knowledge about financial matters.

It is more common to say "business savvy" (as a noun), but "financially savvy" (as an adjective.

> He has a lot of business savvy, and knows when the risks of investment are too high.
>
> He isn't very financially savvy. In fact he runs up big debts on a credit card and then can't pay it back.

Comment: Hi, that was great. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of savvy is having good shrewdness (decision making skills,) and practical knowledge; the ability to make good judgments. Therefore, the definition of financial savvy is knowledge & decision making skills relating to finances (money.)